# Installing OpenCV 3.0.0-dev, issue with configuration options

Tags: opencv, build, compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I know OpenCV 3.0 is not a release version, yet. I'm trying to evaluate a few features in the 3.0 version for a prototype system we are building. I cloned the latest source code from the git repository and I use the following cmake to build the libraries:

```
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

However, I encounter this issue when it builds the libraries when i do a make:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `av_destruct_packet' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I'm not quite sure where to set the -fPIC flag in the CMakeLists.txt. Just a point to note, I have OpenCV 2.4.8 libraries already built and running on my machine. Thanks for taking time to help me out!

Comment: Not sure if answering this is relevant anymore or not. However, I am installing OpenCV 3.0-dev on Ubuntu right now ... using combined steps from http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV .  Will put in an answer for sake of completeness if it works out fine (fingers crossed)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer. I managed to install OpenCV 3.0.0-dev version by removing my existing OpenCV installation. Although this was not required, I removed my previous 2.4.8 library files and managed to compile it. CCMake helped make the decision for the installation much simpler. Use that to decide which libraries you'd like to compile before running make.